# My cat dashes through my apartment at the same time everyday

Tags: cats, behavior, psychology

My 2 year old female cat dashes through my apartment really fast at 6am every morning. She will run from my bedroom to my livingroom really fast as if she's racing with another cat. This is a regular routine for her. I was just wondering if this is a behavioral problem or if this is how she exercises. It's like clock-work. When she does this; it's on an empty stomach because I don't feed her until 6:30am.

Comment: Unless there is something happening at t that time that Starfire her or interested her,  2 may never know. Mine definitely know some times of day -- I get reminded to go to sleep around midnight --but I haven't correlated the occasional mass dash with anything in particular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your cat is exhibiting strange behavior or having a case of the "zoomies," she may just be releasing some stored-up energy after lying around all day.

Nothing is wrong with her, so don't fear! This is a perfectly normal behavior for all animals, especially young dogs and cats.

http://www.petful.com/behaviors/why-does-my-cat-go-crazy-and-run-around/